# Let $k\ge2$ and p an odd prime number. If $g^{p-1}\equiv1[p]$ and $g^{p-1} \not\equiv 1 [p^2]$ then $g^{p^k-1} \equiv 1[p^k]$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

Let $k\ge2$ and p an odd prime number. 
If 
$$g^{p-1}\equiv1[p]$$ 
and
$$g^{p-1} \not\equiv 1 [p^2]$$ then 
$$g^{p^k-1} \equiv 1[p^k]$$
I want to use this lemma:
$$g^n \equiv 1[p^k] \Rightarrow \phi(p^k)|n$$
Where $\phi$ is the euler's phi function.
I tried to work with this lemma, but i don't get results.

Comment: Here     https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227199/order-of-numbers-modulo-p2 we have proved, if modulo order of g is $$d\pmod p,$$ then the modulo order of $g$ will be $$d$$ or $$pd\pmod{p^2}$$ finally use 
   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31679/if-g-is-a-primitive-root-of-p2-where-p-is-an-odd-prime-why-is-g-a-prim

Comment: If k=2 and p=5 and g=2 it is FALSE. Did you copy something incorrectly?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Perhaps it is $k \geq 3$ but unfortunately it was when I copied it.

Comment: The 3rd line is incorrect. I intend to give a complete A later today.