# A composite odd number, not being a power of $3$, is a fermat-pseudoprime to some base

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, pseudoprimes

I want to prove the following statement :

If $n$ is an odd composite number, not being a power of $3$ (or, equivalent,
having a prime factor $p>3$), $n$ is a fermat-pseudoprime to same base $a$,
in other words, there is a number $a$ with $$1<a<n-1$$ and $$a^{n-1}\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n\ )$$

I was able to prove the converse:

If $$a^{n-1}\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n\ )$$ for
some number $a$ with $1<a<n-1$, then the number $o\ :=\ ord_a(n)$ divides
both $n-1$ and $\phi(n)$. Since $o=1$ is impossible because $a\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n\ )$ contradicts $1<a<n-1$ and $\phi(3^k)=2\times 3^{k-1}$ , it follows that
$o=2$. But $a^2\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ 3^k\ )$ implies $a\equiv \pm1\ (\ mod\ 3^k\ )$
because of $gcd(a-1,a+1)\le 2$. But this contradicts $1<a<n-1$, so the number
cannot be a power of $3$

> Is my proof of the converse correct ?
>
> How can I show the original statement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your proof of the converse is correct.

To prove the original statement:

If $n = p^k$ for a prime $p > 3$, then the group of units modulo $n$ is cyclic, and therefore contains an element $a$ of order $p-1 \geqslant 4$. This is a base for which $n$ is a Fermat pseudoprime, and $a \not\equiv \pm 1 \pmod{n}$.

If $n$ has at least two distinct prime factors $p,q$, say $n = p^kq^m\cdot r$ with $\gcd(r,pq) = 1$, then let

$$a \equiv 1 \pmod{p^kr},\quad a \equiv -1 \pmod{q^m}.$$

Then $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$, and $n$ is a Fermat pseudoprime for the base $a$.

Comment: First of all, thanks for checking my proof. Could you explain, why the group of units of $\mathbb Z_{p^k}$ is cyclic, if $p>3$ ?

Comment: It's cyclic for all odd primes $p$, but for $p=3$, we have $p-1= 2$, and then the element of order $p-1$ is $\equiv -1\pmod{n}$, as you noted in the question. If you already know that the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ is cyclic - any finite subgroup of the group of units of a field is cyclic, and $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ is a finite field - then you get it by lifting. Say $r_1$ is a primitive root modulo $p$. Then look at $r_1^{p-1} \equiv 1 + kp\pmod{p^2}$. If $k \neq 0$, then the order of $r_1$ modulo $p^2$ is $p(p-1)$, so $r_1$ is a primitive root modulo $p^2$.

Comment: If $k = 0$, then $(r_1 + p)^{p-1} \equiv r_1^{p-1} + (p-1)r_1^{p-2}p \not\equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$, and $r_2 = r_1 + p$ is a primitive root modulo $p^2$. Continue until you reach $p^k$. If you have $r_m$ such that the order of $r_m$ modulo $p^m$ is $(p-1)\cdot p^{m-1}$, then either $r_m$ has order $(p-1)\cdot p^m$ modulo $p^{m+1}$, or $r_m + p^m$ has order $(p-1)\cdot p^m$ modulo $p^{m+1}$.

Comment: OK, I know that $\mathbb Z_p$ is cyclic, but I must think about the "lifting".

Comment: Is the theorem of Cauchy (every group of order $n$ has an element with order $p$, if $p$ is prime and $p|n$) a useful alternative here ?

Comment: Not really, since we need an order divisible by $p^{k-1}$. Cauchy's theorem would only give us an element whose order is the product of all distinct prime divisors of $(p-1)\cdot p$ (we get that since our group is abelian, so if the orders of $a$ and $b$ are coprime, we have $\operatorname{ord}(ab) = \operatorname{ord}(a)\cdot \operatorname{ord}(b)$). But here, once we have the element of order $p-1$ modulo $p$, all we need is a part of the binomial theorem to get from $p^m$ to $p^{m+1}$.

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/26019) or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/25923) may be helpful.

Comment: I will work through all this, seems a bit complicated ... Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: With some efforts, I understood the procedure.